# How to add custom search link to Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am trying to create a custom search for my users repository. I have a custom restcontroller for it

```
@BasePathAwareController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 20971520)
public class UserController implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<User>>,{

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userReposiotry;

    @Autowired
    private EntityLinks entityLinks;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/getAvatar", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "image/jpg")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadImage(@RequestParam("username") String username)
            throws IOException {

        ClassPathResource file = new ClassPathResource("uploads/" + username+ "/avatar.jpg");

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentLength(file.contentLength())
                .contentType(
                        MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(file.getInputStream()));
    }

    @Override
    public Resource<User> process(Resource<User> resource) {
        LinkBuilder lb = entityLinks.linkFor(User.class);
        resource.add(new Link(lb.toString()));

        **// How can I add the search/getAvatar to the user search resource?**

        return resource;
    }
}
```

The first issue is that I get a 404 when trying to call /users/search/getAvatar?username=Tailor

The second is that how can I add this to the users search links?

Thank you

Comment: try calling `call /users/search/getAvatar/?username=Tailor` instead of `call /users/search/getAvatar?username=Tailor` for your first part. It troubled me few days ago

Comment: The issue seems to be the produces = "image/jpeg" If I remove that it works if I add it return 404 strange. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a search link, you need to extend [RepositorySearchesResource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositorySearchesResource.html) as illustrated here:

- [Spring Data Rest Add custom endpoint to specific reposiotry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031913/spring-data-rest-add-custom-endpoint-to-specific-reposiotry)
- [Spring Data Rest - Add link to search endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778809/spring-data-rest-add-link-to-search-endpoint)

As pointed out in the comments, be sure to check the domain type so as to add search link only for relevant repository.

Comment: Thanks that is working but I already implement the resourceProcessor for adding non search link. How can I add both search and entity links?

Comment: Check the [accepted answer from the second link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32796873/5873923): the class implementing ResourceProcessor<> does not have to be your UserController class. A controller is actually not a resource processor, so it makes sense to implement your resource processors from two separate classes, both distinct from the controller.